# How to roll back or uninstall a script ran from wget piped to bash?

Tags: bash, themes, uninstall, wget

I piped the following script to bash using `wget` with the intention of installing a theme for bash.

```
wget -O - https://teejeetech.com/scripts/jammy/tweak_terminal | bash
```

Now I cannot find a way to roll back or uninstall what I did with this command.

I checked `wget --help` but didn't find anything I can use.

I couldn't find a 'wget' folder either.

Comment: `wget` is just a tool to download something. You can't revert anything by `wget`. You've downloaded and run a script. So look into the script and see what it did.

Comment: Where should i look for this 'tweak_terminal' file. Or should I ?

Comment: Click on the link in your question and you'll see the file. The file should be in your Home directory if you ran the command from there.

Comment: Beware that removing the file won't help.

Comment: It is not hard to revert it really.

Comment: There is always reinstalling your OS from scratch as a fall back option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to shudder/laugh when anything on the internet asks me to `... | bash` . This is like giving your car keys to a masked stranger.

I've been computing since 1967, security focused since 1997, and would do it thusly:

```
wget -O suspect.bash  https://teejeetech.com/scripts/jammy/tweak_terminal
less suspect.bash
# many `man`commands, until
# I understand the script and
# what it does. Does the script 
# have some sort of "uninstall" 
# option?
# Then, remove "echo " when you are confident
echo bash -x ./suspect.bash
```

Now, you'll have to do this process, and determine what each command did, and how to revert the changes. There's no general "undo" function.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by deleting the custom code in `/home/.bashrc`.

Comment: That's not all that the script does. It also changed something in `dconf`.

Comment: And installs packages with `apt` (bash-completion boxes tree fonts-cascadia-code fonts-firacode)